# WSL: Ubuntu on Windows 10, unable to see published topics

Tags: ros, ros2, talker, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm am trying to work with ROS2-eloquent on Ubuntu for Windows 10.  I would like to create multiple nodes that can pass messages to one another while running independently in different terminals.  I can recreate my problem using the talker/listener demo nodes.

I open a new Ubuntu terminal in Windows 10.  Then I run tmux so that I can open multiple terminals in this instance of Ubuntu.  In the first tmux pane, I run

```
source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker
```

The node prints the expected output.

Now i open a new pane in tmux and run

```
source /opt/ros/eloquent/setup.bash
ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener
```

No output prints to the screen making me think that the listener is unable to subscribe to the topic that the talker is publishing.  Now I kill the listener and run

```
ros2 topic list
```

which only prints

```
/parameter_events
/rosout
```

and nothing prints for

```
ros2 topic list
```

All of this works find when I run this on Ubuntu 18.04 running natively.  I'm not familiar with how Ubuntu on Windows 10 operates under the hood and I would appreciate if anyone could help me solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346820/wsl:-ubuntu-on-windows-10,-unable-to-see-published-topics/) by [ghaggin](https://answers.ros.org/users/52203/ghaggin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed by switching to wsl2 on windows insider.

---

Originally posted by [ghaggin](https://answers.ros.org/users/52203/ghaggin/) with karma: 16 on 2020-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cwillia109](https://answers.ros.org/users/51647/cwillia109/) on 2020-05-23**:
For the purposes of multi-machine setups, this will not work. It only allows for ROS2 to work internally withing WSL2.